# Unit testing react component with reference to self

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs

I am quite new to the testing frameworks for React JSX components and I stumbled across one problem when uni testing that a component renders correctly. It contains `ref` to `this` inside its `render` method and I have no idea how to unit test it (or ignore it so the test will not fail).

I am using **chai** for testing.

This is the component:

```
export default class TopTooltip extends Component {
  render() {
    const { ident, title} = this.props;

    return (
      <Tooltip
        className={`${className} top-banner-tooltip`}
        id={ident}
        ref={this}
      >
        foo
      </Tooltip>
    );
  }
}
```

...and my unit test:

```
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { Tooltip } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

describe('TopTooltip', () => {
  describe('renders', () => {
    it('all injected values', () => {
      const t = (<TopTooltip
        title="tooltip"
        ident="xyz"
        className="myClass"
      />);

      const comp = shallow(t);

      expect(comp.find(Tooltip).at(0).node)
       .to.equalJSX(
        <Tooltip
          className="myClass top-banner-tooltip"
          id="xyz"
          ref={t.this}
        >
          <span className="title">tooltip</span>
          foo
        </Tooltip>
      );
    });
  });
});
```

However, this fails because the reference is not as expected:

```
expected ref={[object Object]}
but got ref={undefined}
```

Can anyone help me with this issue? I am even fine with specifying that this reference should be ignored during the test.

Comment: I will suggest you to use the Enzyme (http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/guides/mocha.html) powerful tool to do some test with react. There's also a plugin for chai integration (https://github.com/producthunt/chai-enzyme) :)

Comment: @MichaelRasoahaingo I actually do use enzyme (that's where shallow method comes from). Could you be more specific in which way I should apply it in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
it('should contain <Tooltip/>', () => {
  const component = shallow(<TopTooltip/>);

  expect(component).to.contain(<Tooltip/>);
});


it('should correctly render', () => {
  const component = shallow(<Tooltip className="myClass"/>);

  expect(component).to.have.className('myClass');
  expect(component).to.contain(<span className="title">tooltip</span>);
});
```

Assuming that you have correctly installed chai-enzyme

```
import chai, { expect } from 'chai';
import chaiEnzyme from 'chai-enzyme';

chai.use(chaiEnzyme());
```